# path finding between two points in grid under defined constraints

Tags: java, genetic-algorithm, path-finding

i need to find the possible paths between source and target in a 2*D grid under some defined constraints like
ex: we have a grid (5 * 9) and we have 2 source and 2 targets, i.e.
source1 (2,2)   target1 (4,9)
source2 (2,7)   target2 (4,3)

Now i have to find possible shortest paths combinations between source1 and target1 which donot intersect the path between source2 and target2 with minimum time complexity.?

Can i apply Genetic Algorithm for this problem or keep comparing each path of source1-target1 with all paths of other source2-target2.?
comparing all paths will lead to more time complexity. so suggest me any better solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have in fact no experience with genetic algorithms.

But you might be able to modify an [A* search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)  and let one path block off the other path

Comment: Thanks.
but A* algorithm will give list of shortest paths between respective source and targets and then we can compare each one of them.
but the ex i have given in that case if we consider only shortest paths then there will be no solution.we have to consider all paths and that comparison may lead to stack overflow condition i guess..??